# Give a list of booked rooms for months of May, Jun And July 2009, having price greater than 8000 per day

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

**Tables**

```
Hotel    (hotelNo, HotelName, city)

Room     (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)

Booking  (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo)

Guest    (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)
```

Give the Structured Query Language syntax for the following query based upon the above tables:

Give a list of booked rooms for months of May, Jun And July 2009, having price greater than 8000 per day.

I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
SELECT *
FROM Booking 
WHERE HotleNo IN (SELECT HotelNo FROM Room WHERE Price>8000)
AND (DateFrom>= '2009-05-01' AND dateTo<= '2009-07-31');
```

Comment: If you would read the error message in MySQL, you could have caught the spelling mistake yourself...

Comment: i have not sql server friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below. Since all your information needed can be retrieve from table **Booking** and **Room**, you only need to join the 2 and get the data.

```
select B.* from Booking B
left outer join Room  R   
on    R.roomNo   = B.roomNo
where B.dateFrom >= '2009-05-01'
and   B.dateTo   <=   '2009-07-31'
and   R.price    > 8000
```

Comment: any printsys required ?

Comment: Why a left outer join??

Comment: why the join on HotelNo?

Comment: HotelNo,roomNo and guestNo are primary-key

Comment: I think booking is related to room instead of hotel. and left outer join is to retrieve all booking data, with corresponding room data

Answer (score 2):

The price is a Room attribute not an Hotel attribute. But I guess you might be handling several hotels which overlapping room numbers, so **you have to match roomNo and hotelNo**

```
SELECT *
FROM Booking 
JOIN Room on Booking.roomNo=Room.roomNo and Booking.hotleNo=Room.hotleNo
WHERE Room.Price>8000
AND Booking.DateFrom>= '2009-05-01' 
AND Booking.dateTo<= '2009-07-31'
```

Edit: in your question the field is hotleNo so I'll stick to that field name

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. The join should be on `roomNo`, not `hotelNo`.